# Alternative Using Having in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get the records where avg is greater than 81, I noticed I can't use a simple where avg(score) > 80

But using a Having statement is problematic as well as it does not consider where the individual records average is greater than 80, but it considers the group average. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Please post your schema and some sample data (text, not pictures please).  This is way too vague to be able to answer in anything other than the general sense

Comment: @Kevin unfortunately I can't post schemas due to work restrictions, I just simply want to know how I can get all records from a table where the average is greater than 81

Comment: You can post made up schema/data that is structurally the same without giving away company secrets.  In any event, I made a guess at what you need

Comment: @Kevin check my query

Comment: So you want each question with an average score over 80?

Comment: @Kevin yes each answered question with a score above 80

Comment: confusingly, there are columns in the query are not unqualified (entry_id, entry_group_id, sent_id), and some that are qualified with unknown table aliases (rag.rated_answer) ...  group by is on `ea.question_id` but it doesn't appear in the SELECT list, instead we see `q.question_id`... as way of providing a specification, broken SQL falls way short of sample data and expected output

Comment: @spencer7593 my bad it should be ag.rated_answer

Comment: @spencer7593 I don't know how to provide more information than that in a way to not violate work restrictions, all I want to do is make sure that the scores I am pulling have an average greater than 81, each entry has multiple questions and each question has a score, getting the average of all question scores for an individual entry gives you the average score of that entry. So all I want to do is add a condition to only pull average scores greater than 81, but the way the code is currently written, it pulls the average greater than 81 for answered questions instead of entries..

Comment: @smooky.secrets Wait, previously you said you want all QUESTIONS with an average score >= 81, now you are saying you want all ENTRIES with an average score>=81.  Which is it?

Comment: @Kevin so for each entry, there are multiple questions answered...each question has a score, I am already averaging the entry score, but I am not able to get the ones that are greater than 81

Comment: @smooky.secrets : providing example data and expected output is a much better way of communicating the specification than broken SQL. If you need to ask for assistance, and at the same time protect proprietary information, it would behoove you to come up with some actual dummy table definition and dummy sample data and dummy expected output. As asked, the question is confusing, and is going to leave folks (like Kevin) guessing about what it is you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if we want to return aggregates (SUM,AVG) and also return detail that makes up the aggregate, we typically use two SELECT

As a rudimentary example, consider a table of "test_score"

```
test_id  student_id  score
-------  ----------  -----
    101           6     90
    101           7     71
    101           8     88
    222           6     93
    222           7     78
    222           8     81
```

We can calculate the average score for each test, with a `SELECT ... GROUP BY` query.

```
SELECT r.test_id    AS test_id
     , AVG(r.score) AS avg_score
     , MAX(r.score) AS high_score
  FROM test_score r
 GROUP
    BY r.test_id
```

We expect that to return a resultset like this:

```
test_id  avg_score
-------  ---------
    101         83
    222         84
```

We can use that query as an *inline view* i.e. we wrap it in parens and reference it like a table in the FROM clause of another SELECT.

As a demonstration, to return student scores that were better (or equal to) average for each test:

```
SELECT s.test_id
     , s.avg_score
     , t.student_id
     , t.score
  FROM ( -- inline view to get average score for each test_id
         SELECT r.test_id    AS test_id
              , AVG(r.score) AS avg_score
           FROM test_score r
          GROUP
             BY r.test_id
       ) s
  LEFT
  JOIN test_score t
    ON t.test_id  = s.test_id 
   AND t.score   >= s.avg_score
 ORDER
    BY t.test_id
     , s.score DESC
```

And we'd expect that to return something like:

```
test_id  avg_score  student_id  score
-------  ---------  ----------  -----
    101         83           6     90
    101         83           8     88
    222         84           6     93
```

The first two columns, returned from the inline view, are the result of the aggregate (AVG).  The last two columns are detail rows, matched to the rows from the aggregate result.

---

To summarize the main point here:

To return aggregates along with details, we typically need two SELECT.

One SELECT to get the aggregates (with a GROUP BY if the aggregates are "per" each something or other)

Another SELECT to get the details and a match to the aggregate.

Comment: How would I calculate the average in my case? As you can see I need a lot of joins

Comment: @smooky.secrets : in your case, i think it is exactly the same pattern. First, write a SELECT statement that returns the average per whatever with whatever conditions, with whatever joins are required. Verify that it returns the correct values. Then incorporate that into the FROM clause of an outer query, with whatever joins are required. It's the same pattern.

Comment: where would I put in the condition of >= 81?

Answer (score 0):

If the average score being computed in your query is already correct, you are just having trouble filtering by it, just wrap it in parens and select from it

```
select * from (
SELECT Count(entry_id)                           AS Filled, 
   q.question                                    AS Questions, 
   AVG(ag.score)                                 AS TOTAL 
FROM   entry e
   LEFT JOIN entry_answer ea
          ON ea.entry_id= e.entry
   LEFT JOIN question q 
          ON q.question_id = ea.question_id 
   LEFT JOIN question_group qg 
          ON ea.question_parent_id = qg.question_parent_id 
   LEFT JOIN answer_group ag
          ON ag.question_id = qg.question_parent_id 
   JOIN sent_list using (sent_list_id) 
WHERE
   entry_group_id = 2427
   AND ag.score >= 0 
   AND ea.rated_answer_id = ag.rated_answer_id 
   AND sent_id = 6156 
   AND e.entry_date BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2019-12-31'
   group by ea.question_id
) results where total >= 81
```

Comment: I am using a `group by` statement but that doesn't give the result I want.

Comment: This gives the exact same result as adding a `having avg(ag.score) >= 81` statement after the `group_by` statement